# is_block_type_valid() Error When Running C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was trying to run the following code in Visual Studio. It runs, but shows the below Debug Assertion Failed message. Is there anything missing?

```
int main()
{
    int var = 5;
    int* pPointer1 = &var;
    int* pPointer2 = new int;
    if (pPointer2 == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed." << endl;
    }
    pPointer2 = &var;

    cout << "Pointer1: " << *pPointer1 << endl;
    cout << "Pointer2: " << *pPointer2 << endl;
    cout << pPointer1 << endl << pPointer2 << endl;

    delete pPointer2;
    pPointer2 = 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `delete pPointer2;` is trying to delete `var`, but `var` is a local variable and was never allocated with `new`.  Ka-boom.

Comment: I should also mention that `cout << "Failed." << endl;` is not reachable here. When `new` fails to allocate memory or construct an object an exception is thrown so null pointer value is never returned.

Comment: `pPointer2` can never be `NULL` after the call to `new`.  If `new` fails, an exception is thrown, not a NULL return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are trying to free memory allocated on the stack using delete that is meant for memory allocated on the heap. No surprise there! You also caused a memory leak since you did not free what pointer2 originally was pointing to.

```
pPointer2 = &var; // pointer is pointing to stack
...
delete pPointer2; // deleting in stack, undefined behavior (or just plain wrong)
```